# creating SVG shapes with Mouse

Tags: javascript, svg, svg.js

I use [svg.js](https://github.com/wout/svg.js) together with 3 plugins to create svg drawings with my mouse. My questions is about those plugins. I am using svg.draggable.js, svg.select.js and svg.resize.js. When i try to use the 3 plugins at the same time, it doesnt work.

My html:

```
<script src="svg.js"></script>
<script src="svg.draw.js"></script>
<script src="svg.draggable.js"></script>
<script src="svg.select.js"></script>
<script src="svg.resize.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
<div id="myDrawing"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

my Js:

```
var draw = SVG('myDrawing');
var rect = draw.rect(100,100);
rect.selectize().resize();
rect.draggable();
```

Comment: Help us help you. Please provide an [MCVE](http://www.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Also please explain what "it doesn't work" means exactly.

Comment: Which error messages pop up in the console? Also: did you include the css file of svg.select.js? It's needed to make things work! Furthermore: you include svg.draw.js but never use it in your example  code